# Create Anti Malware Configuration using the API

Tags: api, deepsecurity

Using the API I was able to create an Anti Malware Configuration using Postman. (https://cloudone.trendmicro.com/docs/workload-security/api-reference/#operation/createAntiMalware)

But I still can't figure out why, even if I put some parameters such as ID of existing directory/file/process exclusion into the query, it doesn't apply to it.

I've also tried to modify exclusions on one of them once it is created but it still doesn't work.

Here is what I've done :

1. [Take an ID of a valid exclusion (directory exclusion here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN7F5.png)
2. [Send the query with the right ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57UA1.png)
3. [Get the response from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prVbx.png)
4. [Verify in the Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENDE4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it looks like your syntax is off. Changing `excludedDirectoryListId` to `excludedDirectoryListID` fixed the problem when I reproduced your bug.

When I create queries, I like to copy directly from the docs page using the "copy" button on the top right of the payload, just to make sure that I don't have any small syntax errors.